# Defining nested arrays of recursive structs

Tags: c++

I have a simple recursive struct called `Recursive` and I want to have a const array of it initialized with the values the program needs. Then I'll use a simple iterator function called `IterateAux` and I call it in the `main`. Look at the code till now:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct Recursive
{
    std::string data;
    Recursive* Children;
};

void IterateAux(Recursive* Item)
{
    int i = -1;
    while (Item[++i].data != "")
    {
        std::cout << Item[i].data << "\n";
        if (Item[i].Children)
            IterateAux(Item[i].Children);
    }
}

int main()
{
    IterateAux( (Recursive*)Parent );
    return 0;
}
```

Now if I have my const arrays like this it works:

```
const Recursive Children[] =  {
    {"Child1", NULL},
    {"Child2", NULL},
    {"", NULL}
};

const Recursive Parent[] = {
    {"Parent1", NULL},
    {"Parent2", NULL},
    {"Parent3", Children },
    {"", NULL}
};
```

But the following nested form won't:

```
const Recursive Parent[] = {
    {"Parent1", NULL},
    {"Parent2", NULL},

    {"Parent3", (Recursive[])
        {
            {"Child1",NULL},
            {"Child2",NULL},
            {"", NULL}
        }
    },
    {"", NULL}
};
```

And the question is why? How can I get this to work?

In my investigations, at first I thought the `.children` pointer may be invalid, but when tried with `int` data instead of `std::string` it worked flawlessly.

With `std::string` data GDB crashes with the message `During startup program exited with code 0xc0000135.` so I can't even debug the program! Maybe the array initialization code is making a mess somewhere...

Tried all these on GCC 4.6.

Comment: i got `../sta/recurstruct.cpp:30:3: warning: ISO C++ forbids compound-literals`

Comment: That's just a limitation of the C++ language. You might be able to work around it with some template metaprogramming.

Comment: I had to remove the "const" to get it thru g++ 4.6.3 on Linux, after that it compiled with no warnings.

Answer (score 0):

With a little work I can get it to come up in gdb.  Setting a breakpoint at the while statement in IterateAux.  It goes thru Parent fine, then when t gets to the Children case I see this in the working case:

```
(gdb) p Item[0]
$2 = {data = "Child1", Children = 0x0}
```

and this in the failing case:

```
(gdb) p Item[0]
$2 = {data = <error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0xfffffff4>,
Children = 0x48d24d79}
```

So it looks like the cast to Recursive[] is hiding the fact that it is not compiling to the same form as the first case.

I'm compiling with g++ 4.6.3 with -Wall and getting no warnings.